# HTML merge/overide rules

Tags: html

I am writing an app in which I generate HTML. However some of my HTML comes from an underlying app I cannot control (Flask-Bootstrap). Consequently I find myself wanting to modify some of the HTML that is handed to my app.

Specifically I need to know how HTML combines attributes. Here are two examples.

With metas, is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="shrink-to-fit=no">
```

the same as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

With classes, is

```
<div class="abc" class="efg hij">
```

the same as

```
<div class="abc efg hij">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `class`:

```
<div class="abc" class="efg hij">
```

Here only first class `abc` will be applied to the element and rest all will be discarded. It is different from :

```
<div class="abc efg hij">
```

which would apply all abc, efg and hij classes on the element.

- For meta tag, Both of them means the same.